# Does Teradata support literals for DATE and TIMESTAMP?

Tags: teradata

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

`insert into mydb.mytable (updatetimestamp) values (#1/15/2012 01:03:00#)`

...or...

`select * from mydb.mytable where updatetimestamp = #1/15/2012 01:03:00#`

Using literals wouldn't required the longwindedness of casting and whatnot since it would immediately interpret the expression as a DATE or TIMESTAMP.

Does Teradata support this type of syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Teradata supports the ANSI format for dates and timestamps. Reference: http://www.teradataforum.com/l070316a.htm

For example:

```
INSERT 
  INTO  mydb.mytable (updatetimestamp) 
VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2012-01-15 01:03:00');
```

Or:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM mydb.mytable 
 WHERE updatedate = DATE '2012-01-15';
```